# Rails applicaton's rest client post and put method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Ruby [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client), some example given for put and post request. But it's confusing to me for my rails application's client for sending put and post request. Let say, I have developed my Rail application by commands  : `rails generate scaffold HighScore game:string score:integer` , so here is HighScore controller 2 function

```
class HighScoresController < ApplicationController
  # 1
  # POST /high_scores
  # POST /high_scores.json
  def create

  # 2
  # PATCH/PUT /high_scores/1
  # PATCH/PUT /high_scores/1.json
  def update

end
```

How can I properly execute post and put request from my client side code, for these 2 scaffold related method #1 #2, if I follow this [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) example

Comment: Well the controller's job is to handle the post and put requests not to generate them. You can easily try it out with views in your app. If you just try to make an API without any views, you can just curl the url.

Comment: You can use postman or CURL to check/execute your put/post request in RESTFUL manner.. my friend :)

Comment: @LukeS can you please give me the example code so that I can execute this request put and post. I used this line code for scaffold generated method #1 but it does not works why?  RestClient.post 'http://localhost:3000/high_scores',  { 'game' => 'sss', 'score'=>100}.to_json, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `application_controller.rb` to allow post and put request through an api call.

Change:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

To:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```